# NullPointerException only after I have setServiceAccountUser() for GoogleCredential object (Grails/Java)

Tags: java, grails, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-tasks-api

I receive a `NullPointerException` with very little detail when I attempt to `setServiceAccountUser(ACCOUNT_TO_IMPERSONATE)` on my `GoogleCredential`, build a Google Tasks Service Object and subsequently try to send a request for a list of Tasks from `ACCOUNT_TO_IMPERSONATE`.

```
def credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(P12_FILE)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(GOOGLE_TASK_SCOPES)
    .setServiceAccountUser(ACCOUNT_TO_IMPERSONATE)
    .build()

    credential.refreshToken()
    log.debug("Google Credential Impersonating: ${credential.getServiceAccountUser()}")

    def service = new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build()

    return service
```

Please note that the `credential.getServiceAccountUser()` logs out the expected `ACCOUNT_TO_IMPERSONATE`.

There was a similar issue reported in https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/issues/19

```
StackTrace :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:247)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OAuth2Helper.callRefreshToken(OAuth2Helper.java:70)
at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials.generateCredential(OfflineCredentials.java:144)
...
```

The lack of detail in the error was said to be an issue in older versions of Google Tasks but I have upgraded to the latest version and see no difference.

```
compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0"
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev41-1.19.0'
```

EDIT: After tinkering with the code in the grails console in our web application I can see that executing `credential.refreshToken()` causes the NPE when `ServiceAccountUser` is set.

When I unset the `ServiceAccountUser`, `refreshToken()` is successful. Additionally, trying to retrieve a list of Google Tasks is succcessful for the Service account when the `ServiceAccountUser` is not set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479551/google-drive-oauth-cant-figure-out-how-to-get-re-usable-googlecredentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the reason for the behaviour we were experiencing, but thanks for your suggestions, none-the-less, user1807337 & Srinivasan.

We need to get our application's users to delegate domain-wide authority to our application. This can be done by the organisataion's google apps admin, following the instructions in the sub-section entitled **Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account**

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Here is the explanation given in the same resource:
"If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account with the setServiceAccountUser method of the GoogleCredential factory..."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.Builder credential_origine_builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("[[]]")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(GOOGLE_TASK_SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("cfg/file.p12"));
```

credential_origine_builder.setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com");'

Comment: We are able to authenticate using our service account credentials, the problem is that we are unable to impersonate another user belonging to our domain.